# How to use Azure Arc to deploy containers to local k8s cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, microk8s

We have a local k8s(microk8s) cluster installed at our client.
We use Azure build pipelines and release pipelines to build and deploy to this cluster using a deployment group, that is, we have installed an Azure Agent on the cluster server that executes kubectl commands defined in the release pipeline.

We would like to go from using release pipelines to instead use regular pipelines together with specifying environments for different clusters.

We thought that setting up Azure arc would help us but I don't understand how to use it. I thought that we could deploy to Azure arc and it would in turn deploy to our local cluster, but I can't find any information on how to do this.
Azure arc seems to be set up correctly, I can see my workload and things from the local cluster at least.

If Azure arc is not the solution how do we move away from release pipelines/deployment groups and still being able to deploy to our local cluster?